How does flex container understand his overflow? Could I get flex-wrap behavior for internal container without setting height for it?
I need to implement overflow behavior (wrap or scroll for internal container in case of his overflow by children) but I can't. It's look like that internal container doesn't feel overflow... If I set height explicitly for it, it will work. But I would like to do it without such explicitly setting. Is it possible? what do you mean?
<div class="mega-outer">  
  <div class="extra-pre-outer">
    <div class="test"></div>    
    <div class="extra-outer">
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class="no-flex1"></div>
        <div class="no-flex2"></div>        
        <div class="group">    
          <div class="item"></div>
          <div class="item"></div>
          <div class="item"></div>     
          <div class="item"></div>
          <div class="item"></div>
          <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.3;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.test {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; 
  flex-grow: 1; 
  overflow-y: auto;   
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.no-flex1 {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.no-flex2 {
  height: 30px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.extra-outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.extra-pre-outer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mega-outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
}


https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dyBdNoz

Sorry, this example works for me too, I edited markup and styles for example with existed issue...

I found a solution by myown.
We need to use overflow: hidden for outer containers!
